# How to revert git pull request in tfs online?

Tags: tfs, pull-request

A team member made a pull request using TFS. And completed it, but we want to revert it. When clicking on revert we get this message.

[image]I have this message Pull requests must be completed and not externally merged before they can be reverted

Comment: There's no such thing as "TFS Online". Are you talking about Azure DevOps, or on-prem TFS? If on-prem TFS, what version?

Comment: Was `master` the target branch of PR 1315? If not, then that error message makes sense.

Comment: Git does not have pull requests. GitHub have PRs; GitLab have "MRs" (merge requests); Bitbucket have PRs; other hosting sites probably also have PRs. But Git itself doesn't. The details of how PRs (or MRs) work are specific to the hosting site, since they're add-ons.